# Dropping columns out of loading files into a list

Tags: r, dataframe, col

I'm working with huge data files (several hundred MBs) and need to be as efficient as possible. 
I'm using a lapply function to load all files into a list, but due to the nature of the file origin there are a couple columns that I don't need.

```
dfs <- list.files(pattern="*.txt")
dfss <- lapply(dfs,read.table)
```

I normally use a `drop=c("ID","num")` command with `read.table`:

```
file <- read.table(drop=c("ID","num"))
```

But it won't work here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are your sure you normally run that command since [read.table()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/read.table) does not have a `drop` argument? And where's the file, separator? Plus, you are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`fread`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/functions/fread) function from the *data.table* package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```
dfss <- lapply(dfs,read.table,drop=c("ID","num"))
```